# Getting negative value of Stokes theorem integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I was attempting the question:

Let  $F(x,y,z) = (y, -x, 2z^2+x^2)$ and $S$ be the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 25$ that lies below the plane $z = 4$. Evaluate the expression $\iint \operatorname{curl} F \cdot n \mathrm{d}\sigma$, where $n$ is the unit outward normal of $S$.

I applied Stokes theorem, since the given surface is piecewise smooth orientable & has a piecewise smooth boundary $C$ given by $C : x^2+y^2 = 9$, $z = 4$.

I then parametrized the curve $C$ as $C : r(t) = (3\cos t,3\sin t, 4)$; $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ and proceeded to compute the line integral of $F(r(t))$ over $C$, which evaluates to $-18\pi$.

But the answer given to the problem is $18\pi$, which has the opposite sign of the above answer. The explanation given in the exercise is that the boundary $C$ should be parametrized as $(3\sin t, 3\cos t, 4)$ and that the orientation of $C$ is clockwise when viewed from above.

Can anyone clarify which answer is correct, and why? Is the parametrization $(3\cos t, 3\sin t, 4)$ incorrect?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write your mathematics

Comment: Sorry for whoever was editing/approved editing at the same time as me... Anyway, yeah on this forum you should write maths using MathJax, it's pretty much like LaTeX if you're familiar with that.

Comment: Assuming all else correct, if this was an "upper" part of the sphere with the normal pointing up you would parametrize $C$ in CCW fashion, as you did, but this calls for the opposite.

Comment: @BrunoB yeah we clashed a little, but now it needs some fixing up which could be on me and I can't edit because it's only a character or two (I hate that restriction).

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Fair enough! :)

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Why does the question require the opposite? And how will one deduce the correct parametrization for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize images are discouraged in general; but I did not see another good way to do this.

I've drawn the partial spheres translated away from the origin since it was easier to draw and still illustrates the idea.

The first shows an example where the surface is an "upper" section of a sphere, that is above the cut by a plane $z=c$ and the second is representative of your problem.

In the first, the usual orientation convention for Stokes' theorem means that for the outward normal and the traversal of the boundary to follow a "right-hand" rule, then we require a counter-clockwise orientation of the boundary.

But in the second, for a consistent orientation, it needs to be clockwise. One way to see this is to just imagine flipping the first picture to the second (flip the partial sphere but keep $xyz$-space fixed), and the boundary circle reverses orientation *relative to the coordinate axes* - that is the key point.

This should explain the answer; if anyone has a different (or more rigorous) explanation please share it!

[image]

Comment: Is the "flipping" you describe in the answer the reason why the x and y parameters get interchanged? Are there any cases when other pairs of parameters ( like y and z, x and z) get switched? How do you decide which pair should be interchanged? My major doubt is - how do I figure that (3sint, 3cost, 4) is the correct parametrization for C?

Comment: I am not viewing it as directly switching parameters, rather what is the correct orientation of $C$ for Stokes' theorem. That requires a clockwise traversal of the circle $C$ which is achieved by the parametrization $(\sin t, \cos t$) instead of $(\cos t, \sin t)$. It traverses the circle CW, and starts at $(0,1)$ rather than $(1,0)$ and is the easiest choice not a unique choice.

Comment: Thank you. I finally understand. It seems deciding between (cost,sint) and (sint,cost) can be done by considering the values at t = 0, pi/2, pi and 3pi.2.

Comment: Yes - you are looking to move around the circle clockwise in $xy$-space with the usual orientation.  We get so used to writing $x$ and $y$ axes the way we do that we forget that this is a choice, which leads to drawing $xyz$-space in the *usual* way which becomes the right hand rule which becomes the assumed relationship between the outward normal $\vec n$ and $C$ in Stokes' theorem.